# Creating a multi-row column in latex

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to create a table as below in latex:

[image]

EDIT: This table is made on MS word.

I have tried the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Some text A} & \multirow{2}{*}{Some text B} & Some text C\\
\cline{3-3}
 & & Some text D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But finding it difficult to modify it as per my requirement.

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce the image? That's not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, I want to reproduce the image in Latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow}

    \begin{document}

    {\sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Corpus & Dataset & Accuracy \\
    \hline
    English & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     \multirow{4}{*}{}& & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\
    \hline
    Japanese & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     \multirow{4}{*}{} & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\ \cline{2-3}
     & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is not even the need for `\multirow` since the cells are emtpy anyways.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: It's not needed if the cells are really empty, I agree with you, but I'm not sure they will remain empty in the real situation.